# Unable to Set Initializer for Custom UICollectionView Cell Class

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cosmicmind

I am trying to set an initializer for a custom UICollectionViewCell class and I am receiving an error. I am new to Swift and understand that a model class must have a relevant initializer in order to use items from the class. Here is my code and the error I am receiving:

[image]

Comment: Just click that red warning it should do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a default value to your **key** variable or make it **Optional**

```
var key: String?
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Can you briefly explain the optional requirement, what exactly it means?

Comment: Optional means that your variable allows nil and this case, key will have nil by default and variables declared in your class needs to have a default value

Answer (score 1):

you need to include the initializer for NSCoder:

```
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // do something here if you need ... 
}
```

That should fix it for you.

Comment: I updated with a new error. I am now having issues with my "key" property. And why do I need to use this initializer? Kind of confused....

Comment: Well you are conflating two issues now, which is really not good for StackOverflow searches. Basically, if a value is not optional, it must contain a value. If you do not set one upon declaration of the property, then it must be set in the initializer.

Answer (score 0):

if your 'Key' is not optional then you need to initialize the 'key' in Init().

```
public required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    // do something here if you need ... 
}
```

The decoder is useful if you want to restore your object to customer object.For example, if you store a class object in core data and read the record from core data then you need to do encode and decode for it.